# How to deny access to a given form in C#

Tags: c#

For a project, I want to only gain access to a form, only after another form has been seen

E.G Can only see a form that displays results **after** a form for a lineup has been seen

Comment: What have you tried? We can help better if you show us what you have already

Comment: Zac please add code so when can understand what are you trying to do..

Comment: What kind of application it is? Web Application or Windows Form Application?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a button on your first form and then open your second form from there:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var secondForm = new secondForm();
    secondForm .Show();
    this.Close();
}
```